# This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime. What it means?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows

I see that in many Microsoft APIs like for example [SystemAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx)

I see that there is a statement

> This API cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows
>   Runtime.

I'm not able to understand what does this "WIndows Runtime" mean in this context & how is it different from the applications not running in windows runtime ?

Does it mean the Windows Phone applications/ WIndows metro apps ?

Comment: Windows Phone/Store apps run in a sandbox that enforces rules that WinRT apps must abide to.  There are many, focused on conserving power and giving the user a shot at running a mobile device without needing a virus scanner.  Specific to system(), read the docs for Launcher.LaunchUriAsync() to learn more.